# Bring all click mouseevents in one listener

Tags: actionscript, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I would like to know how to compose a click mouseevent of different objects in one listener, if ever that's possible.

What I wanted to do is make this listener universal for all the button clicks like:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicker);

function clicker (e:MouseEvent):void{

if (frame2_btn is clicked){
gotoAndPlay(3);
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicker);
}

if (frame3_btn is clicked){
gotoAndPlay(4);
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicker);
}

}
```

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's really possible to write such function as all event bubbled through hierarchy (upward direction). And you can get the object that is responsible for generating that event using target attribute.

Here's a demo code for your reference ( For Actionscript and Haxe)

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicker);

function clicker (e:MouseEvent):void{

    if (e.target.name  == "frame2_btn") {
       gotoAndPlay(3);
       stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicker);
    }

    if (e.target.name  == "frame3_btn"){
       gotoAndPlay(4);
       stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicker);
    }
}
```

Just make a extra attribute name in your every object( Sprite, shape,...there are many of them) which makes their identification little easier.

Hope this help you

Best Deepak

Comment: I copy pasted your code but it can't seem to detect the object. I tried tracing and nothing's showing up. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a simple button, it should work no problem, if it's a movieclip, that acts as a button, then the children will give you a different name.

what do you get when you try

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clicker);

function clicker (e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace(e.target.name);
}
```